# Can Moderators please delete my account?

Tags: support, account-suspension, deleted-accounts

My account has been suspended on SO. I request moderators to close or delete my account. I want a new fresh start.

Comment: IMO Wait it out, suspension and deletion happen at low level i.e. on your ip address what if you will not able to create account from your current location.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To request deletion, use the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page on the site (SO, not here on Meta), or reply to the suspension message.

Don't plan to get that fresh start during the period of your suspension, though -- that would be evading a suspension, and is grounds for suspension or deletion of the new account.  If you've been suspended, just wait it out.

Since you're waiting anyway, you might as well keep your account and come back when the suspension is over.  It's only a week.

Comment: there are people visiting my account and that suspension message is removing my real life reputation thats why

Comment: @jaydeepmore Maybe you should make some real-life apologies then instead of trying to sweep whatever the problem was under a rug. Fixing the problem at the source will do a lot more for your real life reputation than a "fresh start". You stand more to gain than to loose.

Comment: okay sir will keep in mind and sure will do @caleb